# Drupal 8 site stuck in maintenance

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I have a Drupal 8 site which has been live and working fine for a while but a few days ago it stopped working and displayed the following :

> This website is temporarily down for maintenance, it will be back online again soon. Please accept our apologies for any inconvenience.

I have tried to access the admin login and any other pages but nothing works and it will just keep displaying the message and I have no idea what to try to fix it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I just tried that URL and I got the same message, i never put the site into maintenance mode so I assume it was an automatic thing which has gone wrong, can I manually change it in the database ?

Comment: 1. Log in (as admin). 2. Access example.com/admin/config/development/maintenance 3. Uncheck `[ ] Put the site in maintenance mode`. Done.

Comment: Database? Let me google that for you ;) https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/166358/how-can-get-my-site-out-of-maintenance-mode

Comment: hey leymannx, i cant access the login or admin at all, every URL I try gives me the same message. that why I though i may be able to change it in the database but I am new to Drupal and dont really know what I'm looking for.

Comment: I have never used drush but should be able to ssh into the server and will give it a try, thanks

Comment: Then it's `drush sset system.maintenance_mode 0 -y`

Comment: Honestly, it's really strange that all sites are giving this message and you can't login anymore. Have you tried example.com/user which is the default login site in Drupal? I hope your site hasn't got hacked.